# unit testing gae with login setting in app.yaml

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, nose, testbed

I'm unit testing a google app engine app that uses the login setting in the app.yaml file.  E.g.,

```
- url: /profile
  script: main.py
  login: required
```

I'm using testbed, nose, nose-gae, and webtest though not sure which of those matter.

My problem is that the login setting from app.yaml is ignored during testing.  So if I don't have a logged in user and call

```
  response = self.app.get("/profile")
```

I get the requested page instead of being redirected to the login page.

Is there a way to test the login settings from app.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using a unit test. Your tests are calling the handler directly, which doesn't involve the `dev_appserver`, which is the component that enforces these restrictions. If you want to test these restrictions, you'll need an end-to-end test that invokes the dev_appserver and calls it over HTTP.

Comment: Could you point me to a resource that explains how to do an "end-to-end test that invokes the dev_appserver and calls it over HTTP"?

Comment: @Jeff I don't think it's well documented anywhere, unfortunately. You'd either have to invoke dev_appserver from the shell, or look into the internals of the SDK to figure out how to invoke it programmatically. You might want to consider if this is worth doing; it would be simpler to move the checks into your code instead of relying on app.yaml, or writing tests that verify the contents of app.yaml instead. The latter is arguably better, since you're then testing your own app, not the dev_appserver.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Definitely not worth a big effort for this so I'll go with one of your simpler solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is almost 2 years later, but [I had a similar problem and came upon a solution that's been developed lately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885277/testing-google-appengine-app-security-as-set-in-app-yaml/15940624#15940624).

There is now a ["regression test framework"](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/downloads/detail?name=test.zip&can=2&q=) for devappserver2, which is the [default development appserver as of 1.7.6](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.6_-_March_19,_2013). It sets up a server that will indeed use the app.yaml security settings and does this kind of integration testing

Comment: Very interesting!  Does this replace webtest as well or do you use it with webtest?

Comment: While it's helpful that the framework fires up a dev server instance that you can test against, I don't think it replaces webtest for fully integration testing GAE. It will handle your app.yaml security checks, but it really doesn't provide much else right now other than a basic url_fetch that gives status, header, and content information. If you were going to do any extensive content checking with it, you might look at extending the BaseTestCase with a method to hand back a webtest.TestApp object.