# Testing Google appengine app security as set in app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What's the way to test the python app security as set up in the app.yaml file?

In my app.yaml, I have a log section that is restricted:

```
- url: /log/?.*
  script: swim.app
  login: required
```

I've a suite of tests for my GAE app (python) and I'd like to add some tests that check that login restriction. I've set up the test runner as [per these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Setting_Up_a_Testing_Framework) and then initialized my stub(s) as they show for the [DemoTestCase earlier in that page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Writing_Datastore_and_Memcache_Tests).

```
def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    # Set consistency policy to simulate HR consistency model
    self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
    self.testbed.init_user_stub()

def tearDown(self):
    self.testbed.deactivate()

...

def test_log_requires_login(self):
    ''' Make sure attempted access redirects to a login page '''
    request = webapp2.Request.blank('/log')
    response = request.get_response(swim.app) 
    self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 302)
```

The test_log_requires_login method won't pass because `response.status_int` passes back a 200 status. If I step through the code in the debugger, it appears as though the page just allows an anonymous user to access the page in the test setup and the `response.body` gives me the form on that page. This is not the behavior of the running app, as a request to the application for '/log' will give a 302 status and redirect to a login page.

I've tried using WebTest to do it too, with the same results. The issue seems to be that the app running through the test framework doesn't use the app.yaml information (makes sense because I'm not actually running the full app). I can write tests that drive the running application to test the security, but it would be handy if I could just run those tests with the rest of the unit/integration tests without requiring the running application. Is there a way to do so?

Update: I've been working with [nosegae](http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/). It seems promising because it actually loads the app.yaml information using GAE dev_appserver and it produced the same mappings that the running app uses. It's not clear yet that those are applied in any way though, because my tests still show that an empty user can access the `login: required` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an early release of the ["regression test framework"](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/downloads/detail?name=test.zip&can=2&q=) for devappserver2, which is the [default development appserver as of 1.7.6](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.6_-_March_19,_2013). It sets up a server that will indeed use the app.yaml security settings and does just what I need in terms of integration testing.